# PHPMailer still sending emails infinitely

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails.
When I execute the code that sends an email to X@Y.Z, I still receive this email, not only onetime, but each time I refresh my inbox I receive many copies of it!
Note: I execute the code one time only!!
So what's wrong?
this is my code:

```
$mail  = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$body  = "bla blas";

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP  
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;       // enable SMTP authentication 
$mail->Host       = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";      
$mail->Port       = 25;         
$mail->Username   = "****";   
$mail->Password   = "****";  

$mail->SetFrom('z@z.z');

$mail->AddReplyTo("z@z.z");

$mail->Subject    = "test";

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress('X@Y.Z');


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  //echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  //echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Code looks fine. Is this all the code executed?

Comment: Yes! I use PHPMailer library

Comment: That is not what I asked.

Comment: yes, this is the all, I use it in my project, I call it when I want to send an email